# How to write an instance of Control.Lens.AT

Tags: haskell, lenses, haskell-lens

I have a data structure that can be understood as analogous to `Data.Map` in that it maps keys of one type to values of another.  I would like to write an instance of `Control.Lens.At` for this type but I cannot ever seem to satisfy all the requirements.

Given `Struct k v` with `lookup`, `insert`, `update`, and `delete`, what must I do to make `instance At (Struct k v)` work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `at` method should return an indexed lens for a given index gets as input your structure and behaves like this:

- On getting, if the key is not present, return `Nothing`, otherwise return the value at the key in the structure.
- On setting, if new value is `Nothing`, remove the key from the structure, otherwise set it (or create it if it's not already there) to the value in the `Just`.
- The index is just the key given to `at`.

This leads to the following code for your requirements:

```
instance At (Struct k v) where
  at key = ilens getter setter
    where getter = (key, lookup key)
          setter s Nothing = delete key s
          setter s (Just newValue) = insert key newValue s
```

I use <strike>`lens` to construct a lens</strike> `ilens` to construct an indexed lens from a getter and a setter. I also assume that your functions have the following types:

```
lookup :: k -> Struct k v -> Maybe v
delete :: k -> Struct k v -> Struct k v
insert :: k -> v -> Struct k v -> Struct k v
-- Insert should override the key when it's already there
```

You still have to define the `IxValue` and `Index` type family instances:

```
type instance IxValue (Struct k v) = v -- A (Struct k v) contains values of type v
type instance Index (Struct k v) = k   -- A (Struct k v) has keys of type k.
```

*EDIT*: Actually, at must return an indexed lens, not just a lens. I also confused the order of the arguments to the setter.

Comment: Note that `lens` (or `ilens`) isn't generally the recommended way to make a lens. It's usually better to write it directly.

Comment: @shachaf Why is that?

Comment: It's generally more verbose and less efficient (no sharing).